# Can blazor webassembly use a 3rd party wasm file

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I have a simple blazor project, basically using the default template in VS2022.  Outside of that I have created a simple wasm file with a cpp function that just adds two numbers together.

```
int TestAddition(int a, int b){
return a + b;
}
```

I can't find any clear information on how to access this wasm file and use the TestAddition inside of the C# code.  Is that possible directly or is there an example out there of how to make this happen.